# how to express the complex where and order Part with odoo's ORM?

Tags: odoo

in odoo 13, I have a custom SQL query, as follows:

```sql
select * from test_table1
where number = self.number and (name=self.name or spec = self.spec）
order by (
    case when name=self.name then 1 else 0 end +
    case when spec=self.spec then 1 else 0 end
) desc
```

I want to know how to express the complex where and order Part with odoo's ORM domain?

---

Actually, my business is, I have a button in a form, click button back to the tree view or the table

```py
def action_genmatchlist(self):
    return {
        'name': 'Gen Match List',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'views': [[False, 'tree']],
        'res_model': 'test.table1',
        'target': 'new',
        'domain': [('number','=',self.number)],
        #'order':???,
    }
```

so,I have three questions about this:

1. how to  express the where and order Part with odoo's ORM?
2. Can I sql query data by format first, and then attach the data to act_ Window parameter？
3. How to return sql query data to web ,use table template.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex query, you can create tree view from sql query and then you can call it from your button.

Demo Example: Purchase product details, show button in purchase order form and once click, it will open the tree view of the sql query.

custom model:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, tools, _

class PurchaseProductDetails(models.Model):
    _name = "purchase.product.details"
    _auto = False

    order_id = fields.Many2one('purchase.order', string='Order Reference')
    currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string='Currency')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product')
    product_qty = fields.Float(string='Quantity', digits='Product Unit of Measure')

    def init(self):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self.env.cr, 'purchase_product_details')
        self.env.cr.execute("""
                CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW purchase_product_details AS (
                    select row_number() OVER () as id,
                    po.id as order_id,po.currency_id , pol.product_id ,pol.product_qty 
                    from purchase_order_line pol inner join 
                    purchase_order po on po.company_id =pol.company_id and po.id=pol.order_id
                    order by 1 desc,4 asc
                )""")
```

Tree view And windows action:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="purchase_product_details_tree">
            <field name="name">Purchase Product Details</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.product.details</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Purchase Product Details" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
                    <field name='order_id'/>
                    <field name='currency_id'/>
                    <field name='product_id'/>
                    <field name='product_qty'/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="purchase_product_details_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="name">Purchase Product Details</field>
            <field name="res_model">purchase.product.details</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>
```

Security access csv file (You need it if you are using Odoo 14 or above):

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_purchase_product_details,access_.purchase.product.details,model_purchase_product_details,,1,1,1,1
```

Add button action to purchase order model.

```
from odoo import  models,_

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order"

    def action_show_details(self):
        return {
            'name': _('Purchase Order Details'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'purchase.product.details',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'domain': [('order_id', '=', self.id)],
            'target': 'current',
        }
```

Add button to purchase order form view:

```
<record id="purchase_order_form_report" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.inherited.form.report</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='action_rfq_send']" position="after">
                    <button name="action_show_details" string="Show Line Details" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: This does not meet my needs. In fact, I click a button on a form, and then the background needs to get the form field parameters. After complex queries based on the parameters, then return the query result on a  tree view.

I've tried to use the sql view. Can only be displayed directly .Complex operation cannot be performed after receiving parameters

My requirements are similar to a stored procedure,but I don't know how to create a model with stored procedures

Comment: This is work as you described, you will click on button on the form and the id of the record will be passed to the tree view action and filter the data depend on that, and you can pass your parameter to the query using context and the query results will show in the tree view.

Comment: I know that I can use context to pass parameters to the query, but I don't know how to use the orm of odoo to implement the query of SQL. example the where and order by part:select * from test_table1
where number = self.number and (name=self.name or spec = self.spec）
order by (
case when name=self.name then 1 else 0 end +
case when spec=self.spec then 1 else 0 end
) desc